# DragAndDrop not work in Selenium e2e test in template list that work with Sortable js

Tags: c#, angular, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to test maintenance of data in after drag and drop action on 'li' element that contain editable fields, but when DragAndDrop has been fired, the whole test blocks...
The strange fact is that if I manually hover the cursor in front of the drop destination, the test restarts and the action ends successfully.

I tried to use other Action methods to build the drag and drop, I tried to use js methods via script injection as well, but it would seem that there is some sortable js mechanism that prevents me from doing the drop correctly.
Thank you all for your attention and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Could you share what you have done so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it looks in my framework. You will need to modify this a bit based on your methods but this should work.

```
var ele1 = driver.FindElement_byXPath("//elementtomove");
var ele2 = driver.FindElement_byXPath("//mydestination");

DragAndDrop(ele1, ele2 );

public static void DragAndDrop(IWebElement element1, IWebElement element2)
    {
        WaitForElementEnabled(element1);
        WaitForElementEnabled(element2);
        var builder = new Actions(_driver);
        var dragAndDrop = builder.ClickAndHold(element1).MoveToElement(element2).Release(element2).Build();
        dragAndDrop.Perform();
    }
```